# PHP sessions causing interference with each other

Tags: php, mysql, session

Any help with this will very appreciated.

I have a simple site that allows users to login and staff members to login. I use php includes to include init.php in my header. This file contains my session_start(); command and my database connection details. Once a user is logged in a logout button is displayed with a welcome message depending on whether they are a user or a staff member. The code for this is as follows,

```
<div id="logout_button" align="right">
<?php 
    if ( isset($_SESSION['firstName'])) //if the global variable firstName has a value assigned carry out the following
     {
    echo "Hello  ". $_SESSION['firstName']; // display hello followed by the firstName of customer
 ?>                             
    <form name="logout" method="post" action="../php/logout.php"> <!-- This button closes the session and clears all variables -->
         <input class ="button" type="submit" value="logout">
    </form>
<?php                           
        }
        else if ( isset($_SESSION['staffId']))                      //if the global variable staffId has a value assigned carry out the following
        {
        echo "Hello staff member ". $_SESSION["staffId"];   // display hello followed by the staffId number
?>                      

                            <form name="logout" method="post" action="../php/logout.php"> <!-- This button closes the session and clears all variables -->
                            <input class ="button" type="submit" value="logout">
                            </form>
<?php 
        }
?>                      

</div>
```

The problem i am having is that if multiple users are logged in at the same time the name displayed is unpredictable. Sometimes it is not their name but someone else who is also logged in.

After research i found out that the default name assigned to a session is PHPSESSID and that a temporary folder is created on the server to hold the variables. I assumed that that there was multiple folders being created with the same name all containing the same session variables. I thought maybe it was displaying the first match it came to.

With more research i found session_id() which randomly generates a unique session id for each user. i added the code session_id(); directly after i start the session however the problem still persists.

my final solution was to the set the name and id uniquely for everyone visiting. The following code is my init.php

```
<?php


    if(session_status !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
    {  
    $timestamp = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    session_name($timestamp);
    session_start($timestamp); //Start the session to pass variables 
    session_id();               #set a random id to separate sessions
    }
    else
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    error_reporting(0); //Stops the users from seeing error messages if connection fails. Stops users seeing your file structure if there is a problem.

    require "../includes/dbconnect.php"; // creates the connection to the database

?>
```

My idea was the create a session name of something like 2015-11-19 18:51:01 combined with a random unique id.The chances of two users logging on at the same exact time and being issued the same random id was near impossible. I soon found out this would create a new session and log each user out every time the pages was refreshed or changed due to the session_start(); not being called before the IF statement. There fore the IF is always executed.

My question is why are these sessions interfering with each other and how do i stop it.

Regards Peakapot

Comment: Store ip and user-agent in the session at login, and when you receive the next request, validate that ip and user-agent from request match the session. If not, invalidate the session because you're getting a session criss-cross somehow (could be a glitch on your server; could be someone hacking).

Comment: Are you talking about users logging in on the same machine, or from various locations?

Comment: This must be a session misconfigurationg. Unless you've got multiple PHP application stacks that are interfering with each other, then this shouldn't be able to happen. One thing you can try to do is namespace your session based on (as the above mentioned) the user's IP address. This will make sure that the session that's available to them is for the IP only. Something like `session_name($ip)`. This may work better for you.

Comment: Also STOP naming your sessions. `session_name($timestamp);` is WRONG. Just do `session_start();`  If you name sessions by timestamps two people who hit the server at once get the same session. Let PHP name the sessions. I.e. just do `session_start()`

Comment: I would say also that @Ohgodwhy has given bad advice. 100 people might access a site from behind a proxy. They'd all have the same IP. If you do `session_name($ip)` they'll all end up with the same session. The sane thing to do is not bother naming sessions yourself. Let PHP come up with a random session identifier. What's the point of giving the session a specific name? It doesn't increase security. It just causes problems.

Comment: The reason i decided to try name the session was because even when i use session_id(); which generates a random identifier for each session i am still getting the problem. this problem is happening when people on different machines log on. I agree the IP could cause problems. How can you misconfiguration be a problem its simply session_start(); at the beginning of  each page hence why i include it on all pages. Is there something i am missing? thanks for the replies

Comment: There is no need to use `session_id();`....just call `session_start();`

Comment: there's also no need for `if(session_status !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)` Your whole code from `if(session_status !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)` through the else can be replaced with just `session_start();`

Comment: @developerwjk have you read the question? I was using only session_start() but i was getting a problem. Hence i why have tried so many more methods. If session_start(); worked i wouldn't be on here.

Comment: If all the users were logging on from behind the same proxy could that cause this problem?

Comment: did you read my first comment? That won't prevent it from happening. But it will mean that when it happens, rather than someone elses' info being shown to someone else, they'll both be kicked out and have to login again. If this is happening with just `session_start()` then there's a problem with your server or network probably.

Comment: That's good to know. Its better than my code being at fault as the site is hosted on godaddy. Ill get onto them. Thanks.